# I want to install visual studio on my mac book pro.Can anyone suggest me best option?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have MacbookPro(i5,8gb ram,512gb hd).I want visual studios for my work purpose. but i came to know i must install windows for this.Here my question is which best way to install windows on my mac book.
1. Bootcamp.
2.Parallel
3.virtualBox.

My requirement is I want visual studio 2010,vs6.0 ,MS SQL Managemnt studio and MS SQL server2008. I want SQL server running in my local machine.

If I am going for Bootcamp what is the partition requirement for windows? I dont want my system getting effected.Can any one suggest me best way.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did this once. I thenk the best solution is install VMWare Fusion and do it all virtual.